# Зависает Telegram бот на обработке CallbackQuery

Tags: c#, winforms, telegram-bot

Создаю сообщение с `InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData`. Далее надо обработать нажатие на кнопку и обработку. Сейчас код просто выводит выбранный результат. Сама проблема заключается в том, что при нажатии на эту кнопку бот просто зависает и не реагирует ни на что, до тех пор пока его не перезапустишь.

Самой обработки тоже не проиходит. Ничего никуда не выводиться, а просто часть с `case UpdateType.CallbackQuery:` просто пропускается. Ошибок никаких не выдает, просто намертво зависает для этого пользователя.

```
private void startBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            botClient.StartReceiving(Update, Error, cancellationToken: cts.Token);
        }

private async Task Update(ITelegramBotClient client, Update update, CancellationToken c_token)
        {
            var message = update.Message;
            logsListBox.Items.Add($"{message.Date}, {message.Chat.Id}: {message.Text}");
            switch (update.Type)
            {
                case UpdateType.Message:
                    if (message.Text == "/start")
                    {
                        _ = await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(
                            chatId: message.Chat.Id,
                            text: "Trying *all the parameters* of `sendMessage` method",
                            parseMode: ParseMode.MarkdownV2,
                            disableNotification: false,
                            replyToMessageId: message.MessageId,
                            replyMarkup: new InlineKeyboardMarkup(new[]
                            {
                                InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("EN", "en"),
                                InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("DE", "de"),
                            }),
                            cancellationToken: c_token);
                    };
                    break;

                case UpdateType.CallbackQuery:
                    var pressedButtonID = update.CallbackQuery.Data;
                    logsListBox.Items.Add($"{pressedButtonID}");
                    _ = await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(
                            chatId: message.Chat.Id,
                            text: pressedButtonID,
                            parseMode: ParseMode.MarkdownV2,
                            cancellationToken: c_token);
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

[image: Пример работы бота]
Вот пример работы. Все работало и реагировало, до тех пор пока не нажал на кнопку "EN", после этого программа даже не видит новых сообщений.

Comment: `logsListBox` - это же элемент `UI`, да? А вы уверены, что вы тут находитесь в основном потоке, чтобы так спокойно взаимодействовать с `UI`? Попробуйте попасть в основной поток через `Invoke`, например как в этом ответе: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17631369/8324991

Comment: @CrazyElf Да, с этим все в порядке. Убирал элементы `UI`, проблема оставалась. Да и во всех случаях кроме `Callback` всё работает корректно

Comment: Точку остановки поставьте и нажимая F10/F11 (с заходом), шагайте по коду, смотря где именно у вас "зависает" и почему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С UI элементами надо работать в UI потоке.

Например так.

```
this.Invoke(() => logsListBox.Items.Add($"{pressedButtonID}"));
```

А еще лучше заведите метод

```
private void Log(string message)
{
    Action action = () => logsListBox.Items.Add(message);
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
        this.Invoke(action);
    else
        action();
}
```

И теперь можно не думая о потоках писать `Log($"{pressedButtonID}");`

---

Есть кросс-платформенный метод сделать то же самое с помощью класса `Progress<T>`. Предыдущий будет работать только в WinForms.

Просто заведите поле

```
private readonly IProgress<string> log;
```

В конструкторе формы допишите после `InitializeComponent();`

```
log = new Progress<string>(m => logsListBox.Items.Add(m));
```

Этот конструктор захватит контекст синхронизации при создании экземпляра.

Теперь можно писать так: `log.Report($"{pressedButtonID}");` всё так же из любого потока.

*Не забудьте применить выбранный подход для всех вызовов из сторонних потоков, а не только в одном месте, с листбоксом нельзя работать из стороннего потока вообще. Именно по этой причине вы могли нарваться на рассинхрон и дедлок (зависание).*

---

Также возможно вы не обрабатываете ошибки в `Error`. Покажите обработчик, дополню ответ, если с ним что-то не так.

---

И последнее. Я не уверен, что бот приспособлен работать в однопоточном контексте синхронизации. Рекомендую явный запуск бота на пуле потоков, это даст гарантию, что не будет странностей из-за UI контекста синхронизации.

```
_ = Task.Run(() => botClient.StartReceiving(Update, Error, cancellationToken: cts.Token));
```